# What is the series to converge with $1/x$ from $(1,\infty)$?

Tags: polynomials, power-series, taylor-expansion

I'm trying to find an alternative series of polynomials that can pssibly converge with $\frac{1}{x}$.

So far I know that the taylor series for $\frac{1}{x}$ is, as  should be known, $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n(-1+x)^n$$

However this only converges from $-1<x<1$

Perhaps there is a series of polynomials that can converge with $1/x$ from $(1,\infty)$. If so what could it be.

Answer (score 3):

If you can find a **sequence** of polynomials $q_n(x)$ that converge to $1/x$ on $(1,\infty)$, you can take the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty p_n(x)$ where
$p_1(x) = q_1(x)$ and $p_n(x) = q_n(x) - q_{n-1}(x)$ for $n \ge 2$.
One possibility is to take $q_n$ to be a suitable Taylor polynomial for 
$1/x$ centred at $x=n$, so that $|q_n(x) - 1/x|$ is small for $1 < x < 2n-1$.